# What's the best way to prevent overflow/underflow attack?

Tags: security

In Solidity, people use a SafeMath library to prevent overflow/underflow attack. So, I wonder what's the best way to prevent overflow/underflow attack for EOS contract. Is there an easy-to-use SafeMath library available?

Answer (score 1):

EOS uses C ++, and C ++ assert can be used to check for overflow or underflow.

ex) assert( quantity + a.quantity >= a.quantity,"integer overflow adding token balance" );

See the link below for this.

https://steemit.com/eos/@dan/eos-example-exchange-contract-and-benefits-of-c


Also, eosio provides eosio_assert to enable various assertions.

Comment: That check only works for unsigned types. Optimizing compilers often strip out that check on signed types since ISO C and ISO C++ make signed overflow undefined behavior. Asset uses signed.

Comment: AFAIK `assert()` is a macro and not active in the production compiled code, instead it is preprocessed out. So this would not prevent attack.